# Python. Обработка файлов в папке

Tags: python, tkinter, table

Есть у нас папка, которую мы находим при помощи команды `filedialog.askdirectory()`. В нашей директории лежат файлы к примеру `doc08211020190123104100_001.jpg`. Должен выполняться цикл (к примеру фор) для тех пор пока файл с таким форматом не будет последним, к примеру "_04.jpg" будет последним. По итогу (самое не понятное) нужно это вывести в таблицу (как я понял это не возможно в GUI (tkinter). По этому нужно сделать это в консольном варианте, чтобы можно было скопировать и вставить в ексель без осложнений (например переменные iz и iy).

- Тут код не нужен программы, как пример показать я думаю не составит труда без кода (который будет в цикле)
- На С# яб наверное переименовал файлы, загрузил бы в грид и по rowcount бы пересчитал, но Python я ещё не освоил в таких местах, по этому попрошу с кодом или инструкцией подробной описать, как мне это сделать.

Comment: В tkinter можно создавать таблицу через `TreeView` (это универсальный контрол, совмещающий в себе функциональность таблицы и дерева). Если нужен просто список файлов - то можно использовать `Listbox`.

Comment: @insolor, вот к примеру код из ответа "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515014/how-do-i-use-tkinter-treeview-to-list-items-in-a-table-of-a-database" ... если мы `tuples = [(iz, iy)] ` засунем в цикл, то он будет перезаписываться или дополнять таблицу?

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее пример, там в цикле данные добавляются в таблицу с помощью метода insert.

Comment: Для полноценного ответа у вас слишком неопределенный вопрос. По поводу таблицы я вам подсказал, но на ответ это не тянет.

Comment: ну по сути остаётся только одна тема: как в Python оставить окончание файлов, к примеру, чтоб он считал 3 символа с конца (названия), а остальное стёр (и тогда можно будет через цикл прогонять каждое изображение по ее номеру)

Comment: Например, с помощью регулярных выражений: https://ideone.com/KS2ZPH

Comment: @insolor, блин, ты на всё ответил по сути на то, что я хотел узнать, но по скольку ты не написал в ответе это, теперь не получится поставить ответ (хотя ты можешь всё копипастить в ответ)
по сути осталось только узнать только одно, это как в TreeView обозначается RowCount (количество столбцов) до которого пойдёт счёт, но я думаю инструкцию если открою, то найду)

Comment: `len(treeview.get_children())`